# setOnKeyListener is not working in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

setOnKeyListner of EditText in dialog is not Working.

The ParameterDialog have one edittext in that we shouldn't able to enter space. So i implementing setOnKeyListener to edittext but still i can enter space.

So how can i get key entered in edittext other than setOnKeyListner()??

```
public void parameterDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final TextInputLayout tnlAddParameter = new TextInputLayout(this);
    final EditText etAddParameter = new EditText(this);
    etAddParameter.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);

    etAddParameter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+keyCode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    tnlAddParameter.addView(etAddParameter);
    builder.setView(tnlAddParameter);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.title_add_parameter)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_template,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String param = etAddParameter.getText().toString().trim();
                        }
                    })

            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
    // create alert dialog
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    // Text change listener to enable/disable Proceed button.
}
```

Comment: you could simply validate edittext for spaces

Comment: While filling edittext, user shouldn't able to add spaces, if user press space key toast message should show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Dunno whether suits your need just try.
It uses text change listener in android.

```
        etAddParameter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                validate(s.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void validate(String s) {

        if (s.contains(" "))
        {
            etAddParameter.setError("Text should not contain space");
        int length = etAddParameter.getText().length();
        if (length > 0) {
            etAddParameter.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can enter space, but it will be validated. and error message will be set,I dont think you can disable space from the default keyboard

Comment: I have edited my answer, try now and check...It wont allow you to type space now

Answer (score 0):

> if your Dialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AppCompatDialog dialog = new AppCompatDialog(getContext(), getTheme()) {
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
              if (1 == 0) { dismiss(); }
              else{
                Log.oneLine("NOT DISMISSING!")
               }
            }

        };  return dialog;
    }
```